# Battery Meter in Windows 8.1 keeps showing "Balanced" a the top

Tags: windows-8.1, battery, power, power-management

I often use High Performance and Power Saver, but the "Balanced" power plan keeps staying at the top and I can't rearrange. How I can change what plans should be shown so I don't have to go to Power Options everytime to change the plans?

Answer (score 0):

You could always delete the power plan - if you never use it, why keep it?

```
powercfg list
```

when run from an admin command prompt will return a list of power plans.  the one with the * next to its name is your current plan.  Most likely, the balanced plan will look like the following:

```
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
```

Once you know which power plan you want to delete, **BACK IT UP** using the following command:

```
powercfg –export balanced.xml 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
```

Once you have done this, you can delete the power plan like so:

```
powercfg –delete 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
```

If you find that you need to reverse the deletion and re-import the power plan - you can do so by using the following command:

```
powercfg –import c:\balanced.xml
```

A word of warning, people have in teh past complained that this has supposedly caused issues on some older windows 7 machines when all the default profiles have been deleted - but I have had both my windows 7 and 8.1 machines stripped back to just "high performance" for as long as I can remember and havent had any problems at all.

Hope this helps

Comment: Obviously I didn't know how to delete the default "Balanced" plan because it's default and I can't even delete. What I want to do isn't to delete the plan but to remove from the battery meter so that it isn't being shown.

Comment: @MegaRodeon I am also in the situation where I mostly use `High Performance` and `Power Saver` battery plans. I think the best way is, instead of having `High Performance` and `Power Saver` together, why not just export the `Power Saver` XML file, and import it as `Balanced` by overwriting the power plan for Power Saver to Balanced? That way, you will technically have `High Performance` and `Power Saver`, with the latter under the alias, `Balanced`.